# BaseTokenizer.enable_truncation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'direction' [PyTorch]

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm facing an error above while trying to tokenize with truncation:

This is the training code:

```
tokenizer = BertWordPieceTokenizer(
          clean_text=True,
          handle_chinese_chars=True,
          strip_accents=True,
          lowercase=True,
      )
tokenizer.train(files="/content/data_all.txt", vocab_size=vocab_size, min_frequency=1, special_tokens=special_tokens)
    
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast(tokenizer_object=tokenizer)
```

This is the mapping function:

```
tokenizer(examples["text"],  truncation=True, padding=True,
                   max_length=max_length, return_special_tokens_mask=True)
```

This is how I install the transformers and the version:

```
!pip install datasets evaluate transformers[sentencepiece]
Collecting transformers[sentencepiece]
  Downloading transformers-4.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 MB)
```

The details of the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py in set_truncation_and_padding(self, padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, stride, pad_to_multiple_of)
    370 
    371             if current != target:
--> 372                 self._tokenizer.enable_truncation(**target)
    373 
    374         if padding_strategy == PaddingStrategy.DO_NOT_PAD:

TypeError: BaseTokenizer.enable_truncation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'direction'
```

At this point, i can't see any related discussion on this, anyone has any idea on this problem?

Thanks in advance.